# Should I delete this question?

Tags: discussion

I asked [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5908/which-is-this-multi-vendor-panel-in-magento) which is answered precisely.

But now I can see some people posting comment which is not related to question but extension mention it like We have better extension or don't use this service instead use this like that.

I want to delete [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5908/which-is-this-multi-vendor-panel-in-magento) question as it also have image with some company name.

Please advice should I delete it?

Answer (score 1):

I deleted off-topic replies and locked your question.

Comment: Thanks Tim. What should I do with screenshot in question?
Should I blur company name or what?

Comment: Whatever you want. I have no problems with it.

Comment: Please delete the question. As it is nothing to do with Magento any ways.

Comment: Well, you can flag your question and community will decide what to do with it. Deleting the question will be unfair to the person who earned reputation points with it.

Comment: Hey Tim, Please delete this question for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please delete the question.